# How to redirect to pop-up after form submission with spring validator messages?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have one JSP page test.jsp in which one button is there "show Form". After clicking "show Form" a form is opening in pop-up which is a jsp page "form.jsp".

For validating the fields of form.jsp I am using Spring validator.

I want to submit the form page in pop-up and show the same "form.jsp" in same popup with spring validator error messages. Anybody having sugestions for this ??

test.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script>
 function showForm()
{

    var requestUrl="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test/show/form;

    try{
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: requestUrl,
            success: function(data){ 
                $("#dialog_form").html(data);
                $("#dialog_form").dialog( "open" );

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log("Error in displaying rights");
            } 
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Error in displaying rights");
    }
}
</script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <input class="button" value="Show Form" type="button" onClick="showForm();">
        <div id="dialog_form"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

form.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="employee"  id="employeeForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test/submit">
        <p>
           <label>Name</label>
            <span ><form:input path="name" id="nameId" /></span> 
            <span class="required" id="nameErrors"><form:errors path="name"/></span>
        </p>
          <p>
           <label>Last Name</label>
            <span ><form:input path="lastName" id="lastNameId" /></span> 
            <span class="required" id="lastNameErrors"><form:errors path="lastName"/></span>
        </p>
      <input class="button" value="Submit" type="submit" id="submitButton">
    </form:form>
```

in TestController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm() {
        mav = new ModelAndView();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
       mav.addObject("employee", emp);
       mav.setViewName("show_form");
        return mav;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView subForm(@ModelAttribut Employee employee, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
            mav = new ModelAndView();
            validator.validate(employee);
           mav.addObject("employee", employee);
           mav.setViewName("show_form");
            return mav;
        }
```

Comment: try this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form ...will surely help

Comment: thanks @Santino'Sonny'Corleone here they have used jquery validation so its working and I am using spring validator. So I need solution using sping validator

Comment: Annotate `Employee employee` with `@Valid` to trigger validation.

Comment: @Bart I did that but when form is on separate page and am submitting and after validation returning to same page its showing the errors. But when i am using same form in pop up and returning to pop up its not showing error messages.